# How do I use JNI with Servlets?

Tags: java, c++, servlets, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNI with Servlets using JNI but I seem to have some problems.

I comply the .class file located at "\WebRoot\WEB-INF\classes" as I cannot comply the .java file as it says that I am missing imports which are clearly at the top of the file. I believe it cant do it correctly as there is no main function but as far as Ive read, it is possible to  use JNI with Servlets.

Anyways, I was able to get the .h file from that .class and I was able to write my C code perfectly with the .h and make a .DLL I put the DLL is in the "\WebRoot\WEB-INF\classes" and also tried it in the "\WebRoot\WEB-INF\lib" but could not get it to work with a no library inthe java.library.path.

Anything to help?

Comment: I would guess that message about missing imports is related to the classpath that you are using when you compile, rather than the statements at the top of your .java file.

Comment: Could I still use the .class file that is generated in the "\WebRoot\WEB-INF\classes"? Using that I was able to comply. The problem is that when I try to access the servlet after launching the deployement, I get the last error I noted.

Answer (score 2):

JNI dependencies are resolved during runtime, not during compile time. If your .java files don't compile, then you indeed have a problem with your Java classes. 
Yes, it is indeed possible to use JNI with servlets, you can load the native library during initialization phase (init method). You also put your DLL files in WEB-INF\classes, among with its dependencies. Then, according to the error messages, you can figure out if there is something wrong with the DLL, its dependencies or import functions.

Comment: When I try to run the deployment, It indeed launched it and creates a .class file. I cannot comply it using the command line of "javac". So why can my IDE comply it and I cant manually?

Comment: What is the error you get from command line? Can you post it?